# Best way to create forum using CraftCMS 4

Tags: plugin-development

I'm currently develop a website using CraftCMS 4 and one part of it is forum, where users can ask and answer questions. What is the best way to create it? I've found a plugin "Website Toolbox Forum", but it uses some third-party service which does not suit my requirements.
Frontend part is not a big deal, the main thing is how it should be managed on backend panel. I thought to use Structure Channel, and from the first view it looks appropriate, but has some stopping points:

- The first structure level should have only entry type "Themes", and editing of this level should be blocked for non-admins
- 2 and 3 structure level should have only entry type "Messages" (2nd level are initial messages, and 3rd level are answers)
- 2 level can have 1000+ entries, so it should be paginated

Is it possible to create such with native Craft functionality? Or I should use other way e.g. create own plugin/module? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it yourself (Craft is quite capable of it), but I wouldn't recommend it. It's a decent bit of work to do a forum properly, especially things like moderation, spam handling, etc. Instead, I'd use off-the-shelf forum software, and an SSO with Craft.

Vanilla Forums is one I've used successfully in the past, and I wrote a free plugin to do the SSO part of it: [Vanilla Forums](https://plugins.craftcms.com/vanillaforums?craft4)

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I have to implement it as a custom plugin. The issue with Vanilla Forums that backend panel is not compliant with Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (when Craft CMS 4 is), which is in my case a requirement. Also it is better to have one admin panel for everything, and not additional one for forums.

Comment: Is there meanwhile a better solution?